# pytest - How can I pass pytest addoption value to pytest parameterize?

Tags: python, pytest

I have to to pass an argument in my pytest command which I am storing in pytest `addoption`. I want to use these values in the pytest `parametrize` function.

Command:

```
pytest --range-from 3 --range-to 5 test.py
```

*conftest.py*:

```py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--range-from", action="store", default="default name")
    parser.addoption("--range-to", action="store", default="default name")
```

*test.py*:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize('migration_id', migration_list[range-from:range-to])
def test_sync_with_migration_list(migration_id):
    migration_instance = migration.parallel(migration_id=migration_id)
    migration_instance.perform_sync_only()
```

I want to use the value of `range-from` and `range-to` inside `parametrize`.

I am not able to use these values. Please suggest how can this can be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple way is assign your command line argument to environment variable and use wherever you want. I am not sure in which manner you want to use the variables then so here i am putting simple print statement inside test.

conftest.py

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--range-from", action="store", default="default name") #Let's say value is :5
    parser.addoption("--range-to", action="store", default="default name") #Lets's say value is 7

def pytest_configure(config):
    os.environ["range_from"]=config.getoption("range-from") 
    os.environ["range_to"]=config.getoption("range-to")
```

test.py:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('migration_id', [os.getenv("range_from"),os.getenv("range_to")])
def test_sync_with_migration_list(migration_id):
    print(migration_id)

Output :
5
7
```

Hope it would help !!

Comment: One small correction: `config.getoption("range_from")`, replacing `-` by `_`. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#dest

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly access the options from `parametrize`, because they not available at load time. You can instead configure the parametrization at run time in `pytest_generate_tests`, where you have acces to the `config` from the `metafunc` argument:

*test.py*

```py
@pytest.hookimpl
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if "migration_id" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        # any error handling omitted
        range_from = int(metafunc.config.getoption("--range-from"))
        range_to = int(metafunc.config.getoption("--range-to"))
        metafunc.parametrize("migration_id",
                             migration_list[range_from:range_to])


def test_sync_with_migration_list(migration_id):
    migration_instance = migration.parallel(migration_id=migration_id)
    migration_instance.perform_sync_only()
```