# Dynamically parametrizing test fixtures with addoption

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I've got a test suite that is working well to test code across two separate databases (SQLite and Postgres).  I want to extend this to run the exact same test suite across upgraded databases (to test that database schema upgrades are working as expected).

The upgrades to run are determined outside of pytest, from a shell script, based on information from Git, which determines what schema versions there are, compares against available upgrade scripts, and then should invoke pytest.  I'd like to use something like:

```
pytest --dbupgrade=v1 --dbupgrade=v2 tests/test-upgrades.py
```

I have the following in `conftest.py`:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
  parser.addoption(
    "--dbupgrade",
    action="append",
    default=[],
    help="list of base schema versions to upgrade"
  )
```

And I've been using parametrized fixtures for the other tests.  I already have all the test cases written and working and I would like to avoid rewriting them to be parametrized themselves as I've seen when searching for a solution using `pytest_generate_tests`.  So where I could easily hardcode:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=['v1', 'v2'])
def myfixture(request):
  ...
```

I would like to do:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=pytest.config.option.get('dbupgrade')
def myfixture(request):
  ...
```

However the results from `pytest_addoption` are available in either the `pytestconfig` fixture, or in the `config` attribute attached to various objects, and I can't find a way to get it in the declaration of the fixture--but I believe it's available by that point.

### Update (workaround)

I don't love it, but I'm pulling the necessary information from environment variables and that's working fine.  Something like:

```
# for this case I prefer this to fail noisily if it fails
schema_versions = os.environ['SCHEMA_VERSIONS'].split(',')

...

@pytest.fixture(params=schema_versions)
def myfixture(request):
  ...
```

Comment: Is this similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64091628/12480730)? The accepted answer also uses environment variables, but I had added an answer to use  `pytest_generate_tests` - maybe this will help you.

Comment: Thanks @MrBeanBremen; I gave it a shot.  It didn't work (I'm sure it's my fault) but the reason I'm not pursuing it further is that this is much less clear than using parameters taken from the environment, because those parameters are part of the fixture's signature.  Dynamic parametrization in this case should be unnecessary for information that is available at invocation of the test suite.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense - environment parameters are a perfectly good way for configuring different test environments.